# How to group adjacent row and sum the data in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I would like to sum the Value and group the adjacent row in SQL as shown below. May I know how to do that?

My code now:

```
Select ID, Value from Table_1
```

[image: Example]

Further question

how about this?

[image: Further_Example]

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a typical gaps and island problem.

As a starter: keep in mind that SQL tables represents unordered set of rows. So for your question to be solved, you need a column that defines the ordering of rows across the table - I assumed `ordering_id`.

Here is an approach that uses the difference between `row_numbers()` to build the groups of adjacent rows having the same `id`:

```
select 
    id,
    sum(value) value
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        row_number() over(order by ordering_id) rn1
        row_number() over(partition by id order by ordering_id) rn2
    from mytable t
) t
group by id, rn1 - rn2
```

If you want this on a *per user* basis:

```
select 
    user,
    id,
    sum(value) value
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by user order by ordering_id) rn1
        row_number() over(partition by user, id order by ordering_id) rn2
    from mytable t
) t
group by user, id, rn1 - rn2
```

Comment: May I know how to modify the code when I have 2 user? 
you may refer to the further screenshot